# Firefox extension: Handle file save dialogs

Tags: firefox, savefiledialog

Some of the webpages I visit have stubborn save file dialogs for executables. I would like to do one of the following using an extension:

1. Save the file by default and close the dialog box. I looked at http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions It doesn't really work for these files (the problem is described at: http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions under 'Unable to set automatic action. I verified the headers.)

   I guess I can use browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone from https:// developer.mozilla.org/en/Download_Manager_preferences , if I figure out the first part :)
2. Suppress the download manager from showing any such dialogs altogether.

I found https:// developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDownloadManager#addListener() and https:// developer.mozilla.org/en/Download_Manager_improvements_in_Firefox_3 that look promising. I don't really know how to extract the source URI for the transfer either. I'm curious if anyone has any existing examples for using these or if there's a better way to do this. Or if someone knows what part of Firefox's code I could poke, that would be useful too.

Thanks!

PS: Sorry,I had to break the hyper-links above with an unnecessary space after https:// - apparently I need 10 reputation to do that :)

Comment: Also, I learned that standard ways of suppressing Modal Dialogs don't work because these dialogs are of 'unknownContentType'. I couldn't find anything useful when I looked for information on it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I managed to work around this - though my solution probably wont work for most others.

Fortunately I'm behind a proxy I control, so I just corrected the obnoxious headers (Content-Disposition and Content-Type) before they reached Firefox. These were forcing Firefox to open the File Save Dialog box despite my specified preference to 'Always save file of this type'. Furthermore, I set 'browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone' property to True. Works for me, and I cruise through such sites w.o being interrupted.